# Angular 6, router navigation does not load component view but url gets change

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

Router navigation does not loads the component, only url gets changed. When I refresh the page and use the same navigation it works. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am using preloadingStrategy:customPreloading and  onSameUrlNavigation: "reload" within app.module.ts and my app.routes.ts contains route to components module

```
{ path: 'directory/:domain', loadChildren: 'app/users/users.module#userModule' },
```

users.module.ts contains

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        userRoutes,
        AddNewUserModule,
        EditUserModule,
        UserListModule
    ],
})

user.routing.ts


 const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'add-new-user', component: AddNewUserComponent
        },
    ]
    export const userRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

When I refresh the browser and access the route it works fine but when i load my site and login and when i route the add-new-user page the URL gets changed but component UI is not getting displayed but on subsequent refresh of browser works. I am also using routing guards but it is not denying my route neither there is any navigation cancel triggered.

Does anyone know how to fix this?? Would really appreciate the efforts.

Comment: What is the error you are getting on the console?

Comment: is the url is that you are redirecting to is dynamic ? 
something like ab.com/:customparam

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could please share a Minimal Working Sample StackBlitz replicating your issue.

Comment: Ya it is dynamic route users/:domain/add-new-user

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your AddNewUserComponent come from a different module than your UserModule, you might want to add a entryComponent property in your module and import your component that way :

```
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [ SharedModule, userRoutes, AddNewUserModule, EditUserModule, UserListModule ], 
  entryComponents: [AddNewUserComponent] 
})
```

Actually, when you want to use a component without calling it with **html selector** you have to import it in `entryComponents`

Comment: I even tried to change the implementation of routes but still getting the same issue

Comment: I assume you have exported your `AddNewUserComponent` in your `AddNewUserModule` ?

Comment: No I havent exported component

Comment: So if you try to add an exports property in your `AddNewUserModule` which would look like this : `exports: [AddNewUserComponent]` you could retry both with and withouth the entryComponent property in your `UserModule`

Comment: Issue resolved since i have used *ngIf directive with router-outlet and was not triggering any change detection so was this behavior, but now handled the change detection

Comment: @pm2530 How did you implemented this change detection mechanism?

Comment: @pm2530 I am also interested in knowing that how did you implement this change detection strategy?